# Bitcoin RPC connection

Tags: python-3.x, rpc, bitcoind

I am trying to insert bitcoin transactions into MongoDB using python3. Below is my code :

```
import pymongo
import sys
import json
import time
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://xxx:xxx@ipaddress:port")

def getTransaction():
    addresses = []
    txa = []
    commands = [ [ "getblockhash", height] for height in range(400000,550000) ]
    #print(commands)

    block_hashes = rpc_connection.batch_(commands)
    blocks = rpc_connection.batch_([ [ "getblock", h ] for h in block_hashes ])
    print(blocks)
    for txpre in blocks:
        #print(txpre)
        for txs in txpre["tx"]:
            txa.append(txs)
    trans = conTransaction(txa)
    return trans
```

I am getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "Test06.py", line 252, in getBTCTransaction
    block_hashes = rpc_connection.batch_(commands)
  File "/home/administrator/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py", line 165, in batch_
    'Content-type': 'application/json'})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I checked bitcoind  rpc connection,its connected.
   `block_hashes = rpc_connection.batch_(commands)` this code line is giving error. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. After doing changes in bitcoin config file, I just reduce the range of records to be inserted. RPC server cannot handle loads of data at one time. Otherwise, server down problem occurs and connection failed. Max 100 records get inserted at a time or less than that. And one more thing, keep restarting bitcoind RPC server by stop and start commands given below:

```
sudo killall bitcoind
bitcoind -daemon -rpcuser=xxx -rpcpassword=xxx -txindex -rpcallowip=youripaddress
```

Comment: Please do not stop bitcoind with kill, please use the stop rpc command.